# Função de validação customizada html5

Tags: javascript, html5, validação

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de sobrescrever a função que faz a validação de um campo no html5, noto que os browser's implementam de forma elegante um alerta flutuante, eu desejo ter um teste customizado no qual eu verifique CPF e outros dados não simples.

Basicamente quero usar os meios do browser mas com javascript implementar uma validação diferente sobrescrevendo a validação que o browser usa naquele tipo e até implementar novos tipos.

Gostaria sim de implementar algo que me permitisse criar um campo de input que valide CPF, CNPJ, url diferente do que o browser implementa, e até email, porem sem perder a forma de exibição que os browser's hoje nos dá que é bem elegante a meu ver.

Comment: [Como validar formulário antes de enviar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221066/validar-formul%C3%A1rio-antes-de-enviar)

Comment: Desculpe amigo, gostaria sim de implementar algo que me permitisse criar um campo de input que valide CPF, CNPJ, url diferente do que o browser implementa, e até email, porem sem perder a forma de exibição que os browser's hoje nos dá que é bem elegante a meu ver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já viu algo sobre o jquery validate e jquery validate unobtrusive? Eles adicionam uma camada de validação e permitem que você utilize a forma padrão de notificação dos browsers